# Can't seem to trigger the RSI alerts that I have set ? Yet everthing seems to be working with Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, alerts

I'm using the original source code for the tradingview RSI indicator and I'm trying to tweak it to send me alerts when the RSI signal is coming out of overbought or oversold. I feel like I'm almost there but I'm missing something to allow me to adjust the alerts? To be completely honest I don't know what I'm missing I need some help on this one big time.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")

//Get Values
len = input(10, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, "Source", type = input.source)
up = rma(max(change(src), 0), len)
down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
overbought = input(title="OB",defval=70)
oversold = input(title="OS",defval=30)

//RSI Value
rsiValue = rsi(src, len)
rsiOverbought = barstate.isconfirmed and crossunder(rsiValue, overbought)
rsiOversold = barstate.isconfirmed and crossover(rsiValue, oversold)

//Alerts
alertcondition(rsiOverbought, title = "Overbought", message = "{{close}}")
alertcondition(rsiOversold, title = "Oversold", message = "{{close}}")
    
// Plotted Values    
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#7E57C2)
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
bandm = hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(band1, band0, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="Background")
```

Any help would be so awesome and thanks!

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to create an alert from the alert manager. You can do so by clicking the alert button on the top or right toolbar, or simply pressing ALT + A.

https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000595315-how-to-set-up-alerts/

Click this link to read more about how to set them up.

This should fix it.

```
rsiOverbought = barssince(rsiValue > overbought) == 1
rsiOversold = barssince(rsiValue < oversold) == 1
```

**Edit 2:**

```
//@version=4
study(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")

//Get Values
len = input(10, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, "Source", type = input.source)
up = rma(max(change(src), 0), len)
down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
overbought = input(title="OB",defval=70)
oversold = input(title="OS",defval=30)

//RSI Value
rsiValue = rsi(src, len)
rsiOverbought = barssince(rsiValue > overbought) == 1
rsiOversold = barssince(rsiValue < oversold) == 1

bgcolor(rsiOverbought ? color.green : na)
bgcolor(rsiOversold ? color.blue : na)

//Alerts
alertcondition(rsiOverbought, title = "Overbought", message = "{{close}}")
alertcondition(rsiOversold, title = "Oversold", message = "{{close}}")
    
// Plotted Values    
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#7E57C2)
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
bandm = hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(band1, band0, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="Background")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did just that! I created the alert in the alert manager and it doesn't fire at all. Is there something missing or done improperly in the code?

Comment: Edited my answer, it should fix it.

Comment: Awesome I'm trying that now just waiting for it to fire on the ES mini. Will this code be sure to allow the alret to fire when crossing under the overbought line? or does it fire when it first crosses up the line? Big time thank as well!

Comment: Actually didn't check, you can change it and check using bgcolor(barssince(rsiValue > overbought) == 1 ? color.green : na)

Comment: Yeah I tried it and it doesn't light anything up? Weird. But this is an indicator and not an overlayed whole script. Maybe thats why?

Comment: Colors the background of the RSI indicator on mine.

Comment: Edited my answer again, I posted the full code. Colors the bg of the RSI indicator on mine.